# Adding leafs to a tree not showing up correctly as they should

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm making a forest pack and I've got everything down except for the leaves, the only problem is that I don't know how to get the leafs to the right scale and rotation so that they don't show up "wierd" and my goal is to make the leafs look like in the following image:

[image: This is one option of how I want my pine tree to look.]

But currently my tree looks like this (the one on the left):

[image: My tree is the one on the left.]

I want to know how I can make my tree (the one on the left in the second image) look the the other two trees, I am using the Sapling add-on in Blender 2.75.

Any help on how to get the leafs of the pine tree to look more professional and how they're supposed to will be greatly appreciated. 
I am using a leaf texture from CG textures (now [Textures.com](http://www.textures.com)).